# What is the highest order of derivative of this function $f(x) = x^5\sin(\frac{1}{x}) $ at $x=0$?

Tags: functions, derivatives

The function is defined as $f(x) = x^5\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \quad \text{for} \quad x\neq 0 \quad $ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$. 
I can't tell by just looking at the plot. I think there might be a theorem I can use to find this but I'm not so sure.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to ask what is the highest order of derivative which is continuous at $0$?

Comment: @wisher he asks whats the largest integer n such that $f^{(n)}(0)$ exists.

Comment: The highest order derivative that exists is $f''(0)$. I'm not sure that there's a better way than just calculating the derivatives the normal way for $x \ne 0$ and taking the necessary limits for the derivatives at zero. If you wanted to be very systematic, you could prove a theorem by induction on $n$ about the general form of $f^{(n)}(x)$ for a function of this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a software we compute $f'(x)=-x^3\cos(1/x)+5x^4\sin(1/x)$ and $f''(x)=-8x^2\cos(1/x)-x\sin(1/x)+20x^3\sin(1/x)$ for $x=0$. For $0$ we get $0=f'(0)=f''(0)$. But for the third derivative: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f''(x)-f''(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}-8x\cos(1/x)-\sin(1/x)+20x^2\sin(1/x)$ which doesn't exist cause we all know that $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(1/x)$ doesn't exists. So the largest $n$ such that $f^{(n)}(0)$ exists is $2$. There may be a theorem using polynomials to show that the derivatives of $x^n\sin(1/x)$ are something like $a_m x^m g_m(x)+...+a_0x^0g_0(x)$ where the $g_i$'s are either $\sin(1/x)$ or $\cos(1/x)$.